# Traefik memory utilization under high load

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, traefik

I've been running traefik on K8S and under normal conditions it is working well, but when going from a few hundred concurrent requests to a few thousand concurrent requests I am seeing the behavior shift dramatically.

The CPU and memory usage spike and responses start timing out.

Does traefik freak out when it hits a memory ceiling? Any other reasons this would happen?

Comment: We'd need to look at a performance profile to help determining the exact reason. Could you please generate and share pprof dumps per this guideline: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/2673#issuecomment-373022820